# Dateformat converting IST to GMT

Tags: java

Problem in converting `IST` to `GMT`.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");

String input = "05:30:00 IST";
Date d = df.parse(input);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);



System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

getting `Thu Jan 01 03:30:00 GMT 1970` as output instead of `Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970`

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");`

Comment: Do you mean Indian Standard Time or Israel Standard Time? You should use a less ambiguous timezone identifier.

Comment: @andyTurner : thanks IST was atually the problem here :)

Comment: @squal Added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be wary of using three-letter abbreviations of timezones because they are ambiguous. In this case, IST could refer to:

- Indian Standard Time (UTC+0530)
- Israel Standard Time (UTC+02)
- Irish Standard Time (UTC+01)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) lists some common timezone abbreviations; examples of other ambiguous common abbreviations are:

- AM(S)T
- AST
- BST
- CDT
- CST
- ECT
- FKST
- GST
- MST

It is better to use either a UTC offset (e.g. `+0530` for Indian Standard Time) or a uniquely-defined timezone identifier (e.g. `Asia/Calcutta`)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with what you seem to be trying to do here.

- You are trying to use a `java.util.Date` object to contain just a time-of-day (hours, minutes, seconds). A `java.util.Date` object is not suitable for that purpose. A `java.util.Date` object is really a timestamp - it represents an "absolute" moment in time, counted as a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
- A `java.util.Date` object does not contain timezone information. You cannot convert a `Date` object from one timezone to another timezone, because the `Date` object simply does not contain information about a timezone.
- Converting a time-of-day from one timezone to another cannot be done if you only know the hours, minutes and seconds. The result also depends on the date (year, month, day) - the results can be influenced by daylight savings transitions. So it's not possible to convert a time-of-day from one timezone to another if you don't know the date.

If you use the Java 8 `java.time` API, then it's easy; use `ZonedDateTime`, which does contain information about the timezone.

```
// Assuming that with "IST" you mean India Standard Time
ZonedDateTime input = ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 3, 23, 5, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
System.out.println(input);

ZonedDateTime output = input.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
System.out.println(output);
```

If you want to use the old `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` API, then you set the timezone on the `DateFormat` object that you use to display the date - not on the `Date` object itself:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
cal.set(2015, Calendar.MARCH, 23, 5, 30, 0);

Date input = cal.getTime();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
System.out.println(df.format(input));

df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(df.format(input));
```

Comment: thanks jesper, by just specifying the time the Date object takes jan 1, 1970 as the default date. So I think that wouldn't be a problem. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: the timezone was really the problem here. correcting it to +0530 solved the  problem

Comment: Always using 01-01-1970 is a problem if you need to know the time difference when a daylight savings change is happening. `Date` is not a suitable type for storing just a time-of-day. You can choose to ignore those facts and your program will seem to work like you expect - but you'll discover sooner or later that it is based on fundamentally flawed ideas.